# struct with list<..> in 2 dim. dynamic array segfaults on delete

Tags: c++, stl, struct, segmentation-fault

for a little project i wanted to use a struct with an stl container in it.
This thingy is then packet into a dynamic 2 dim. array, but when i try to delete it,
it segfaults.

Here is the code:

```
struct cell{
    list<pair<double, double> > alist;

};
int main()
{
   struct cell ** myAr = new cell*[5];
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      myAr[i] = new cell[5];

   for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
      delete myAr[j];
   delete myAr; 

   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.
Flo.

Answer (score 6):

Use `delete[]` for memory allocated with `new[]`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    delete[] myAr[j];
delete[] myAr;
```

Answer (score 2):

You allocated with new[] so you need to free with delete[]:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
      delete [] myAr[j];
   delete [] myAr;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
   struct cell ** myAr = new cell*[5];
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      myAr[i] = new cell[5];

   for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
      {
       delete[] myAr[j];
       myAr[j] = 0;
       }
   delete[] myAr; 
   myAr = 0;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think `delete [] myAr;` should work fine

Comment: And `delete [] myAr[j]` as well; they were also allocated with `new[]`.